# How to use group function in self join?

Tags: oracle, join, subquery

I want to convert Subquery into Join, following is the subquery

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary)
FROM employees);
```

I wrote following join, but I am getting "ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here" error

```
SELECT e.employee_id,
  e.last_name,
  e.salary
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN employees average
ON(e.salary>AVG(average.salary));
```

Comment: Please explain verbally what a result do you want to get using that join. For now you shoved us a subquery, and another query which is wrong - it's hard to guess looking at wrong code what is your intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this like

```
SELECT e.employee_id,
  e.last_name,
  e.salary
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN (select AVG(salary) salary from employees ) average
ON (e.salary > average.salary)
Group by e.employee_id;
```

Comment: He can't use this, since it won't compile. e.last_name and e.salary are not group by expressions. Why do you need to group by e.employee_id anyway?